# SQL - SSMS2005 - How do I copy a database diagram to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a simple method for copying a database diagram from one database server to another?

I have a diagram on a development server that needs to be moved to the production server.

Thanks

(Sql server 2005, SSMS2005 Express)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, database diagrams are stored in the sysdiagrams table. You should be able to use the Import/Export wizard to copy the diagram data from one server to another. I ran a quick test and was able to copy a diagram from one database to another of the same server using the wizard. This was tested on a SQL Server 2005 Standard installation.

Answer (score 4):

you can try codeproject [Script SQL Server 2005 diagrams to a file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ScriptDiagram2005.aspx)